# How do I pass a function as the context argument?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to pass a delegate in the context and trying to do something like this:

```
    func process(value: Float) -> Float {
        return value * 999.9
    }
-----------
    self.pushControllerWithName("someController", context: [
        "func": SomeUtils.process,
        "someValue": 1
    ])
```

In `someController`, I'm trying to do something like this in the init:

```
var contextFunc = context as func
contextFunc(123)
```

This isn't working giving an error of: `'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'Key'`

Comment: The error comes from the line of pushContollerWithName ?

Comment: Yes, with the line with the "func" key.

Comment: Could you post the signature of method pushControllerWithName()?

Comment: Also please post the full context in which you are trying to call this method.

Comment: I think the problem is that function has compound type, written here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html This means AnyObject is a named type, and you cannot pass a function as AnyObject, because they are two completely different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty clever, but you're colliding with several subtle type problems. And as usual, the biggest culprits are `Any` and `AnyObject`. You should try to avoid these whenever possible.

Your first problem is this:

```
[
    "func": SomeUtils.process,
    "someValue": 1
]
```

That defines a `[String: Any]`, which cannot be converted to an `AnyObject`. You can't bridge an `Any` (like `Float -> Float`) to `NSDictionary`. You need an `AnyObject`.

Your second problem is that your use of `contextFunc` is not consistent with the data you're passing. `context` is not `Float->Float`. It's `[String:Any]`. This may just be a mistake in how you asked the question.

So how to fix it? You need an `AnyObject`. What's the simplest `AnyObject`? An object of course:

```
class Context {
    let f: Float -> Float
    let value: Int
    init(f: Float -> Float, value: Int) {
        self.f = f
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Now you can just pass one of those:

```
self.pushControllerWithName("someController", 
    context: Context(f: SomeUtils.process, value: 1))
```

And you can unload it like this:

```
if let context = context as? Context {
    let contextFunc = context.f
    let result = contextFunc(123)
}
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, creating a separate class ended up being much cleaner. I was bringing in too much JavaScript baggage ;)